# css animation on hover - pause after complete

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a div over an image, which I would like to change his position with css animation from the top of the image to the bottom (triggered with hover), and to stay at the bottom with his new value after the animation (I try not to use jQuery).

So for now I run the animation when it's hovered, and when it's not it's paused. and with the animation-fill-mode: forwards it works , the only thing is that i have to keep the hover for the animation to complete. my code:

```
 <div class="home-posts-section">
        <div class="home-posts-top-content">
            <img src="images/worldmap.jpg" >
                <div class="uael-post__content-wrap">
                    <h1>some content</h1>
                        <p>some more content</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>


   .home-posts-top-content{
width:400px;
height:400px;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}

.home-posts-top-content img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.uael-post__content-wrap{
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    ;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
}



.home-posts-section .home-posts-top-content .uael-post__content-wrap{
 -webkit-animation: scroll_to_bottom 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
-moz-animation: scroll_to_bottom 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
-ms-animation: scroll_to_bottom 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
 -o-animation: scroll_to_bottom 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
animation: scroll_to_bottom 2s;
   -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.home-posts-section .home-posts-top-content .uael-post__content-wrap:hover{
     -webkit-animation-play-state:running;  

}


@keyframes scroll_to_top {
    from { top: 258px; }
    to   { top: 25px; }
    }

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes scroll_to_top {
    from { top: 258px; }
    to   { top: 25px; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes scroll_to_top {
    from { top: 258px; }
    to   { top: 25px; }
}
```

I'm trying to find a way where the div changes his position on hover and stays there. 
Thanks

Comment: please add relevant html for the element in question.

Comment: ok I edited my question and added the html

Comment: You mean, you want an element to be in a state that was triggered by a rule using the `:hover` pseudo class, when it is not actually hovered any more? That is not possible.

Comment: Yes. I want the hover to trigger the animation, and the animation to be complete without being depended on the hover any more

Comment: That is not possible. `:hover` is a _state_, the element can either be in that state, or not in that state. Anything you apply using `:hover`, does not apply any more, when the element is not in that state any more. What you want needs JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `houve`css to update the position of div like this sample

```
.uael-post__content-wrap:hover{
  //do what ever you want 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: you want to move the div when hover it so if you use the code above you can change the position of when houver it